# Manually handle stripe checkout window with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for credit card information. But I implemented my own shipping information form. I want that the shipping information form invalidated before credit card information can be added. My problem is that I don't know how to prevent the stripe window to open.
The stripe button is implemented as

```
<div class="shipping_validation">
     <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" id='stripe-button'
         data-key="{{ key }}" 
         data-zip-code="true" 
         data-billing-address="true" 
         data-shipping-address="false" 
         data-description="benty-shop" 
         data-image="/static/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png"
         data-amount="{{ orders | sum(attribute='cost')*100 }}" 
         data-locale="auto"
         disabled>
     </script>
 </div>
```

I embedded the button in a div element, and I use the class of that element to trigger a form validation for the shipping form

```
$(".shipping_validation").click(function(event) {
    $("#checkout_form").formValidation('validate');
    if(!$('#checkout_form').data('formValidation').isValid()){
       event.preventDefault();
       // do something to prevent the stripe window to open
    }
})
```

I was hoping that event.preventDefault(); would do the trick, but the stripe window still opens. Any idea how I can prevent the stripe window from opening?

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your case you have to implement custom integration for custom behaviour of Stripe checkout. Details are [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom)**

You have to create a `handler` to control the `open()` and `close()` event.

The following example is like your situation using custom integration

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_key....',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    $("#checkout_form").formValidation('validate');
    if($('#checkout_form').data('formValidation').isValid()){ //if your form is valid
        popup(); //open the Stripe checkout
    }
});

function popup(){
    // Open Checkout with further options:
      handler.open({
        name: 'you will put the name',
        description: 'your description',
        zipCode: true,
        currency: 'usd',
        amount: 0000
      });
      e.preventDefault();
}

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Stripe's window opening is not a default action. Default actions are things like the browser scrolling down when the spacebar is pressed. In this case, a `div` does not have a default `click` action, so `preventDefault()` cannot help you because it has nothing to do.

Instead, use [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent other scripts (namely, checkout.js) from receiving the click event and thereby being able to act upon it.

```
if(!$('#checkout_form').data('formValidation').isValid()){
   event.stopPropagation();
   // do something to prevent the stripe window to open
}
```

An alternative approach is to use Checkout's [Custom mode](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), which provides an `open()` method that you can call to trigger the pop-up on demand. Just be sure to still call it within a `click` handler, as browsers like to block pop-ups that are not directly initiated by the user.

Comment: thanks Seth, but stopPropagation() doesn't seem to work either... can it be that checkout.js receives the event before my own js code?

Comment: Yes, that could potentially be happening. If checkout.js is being imported before the script that registers your event listener whose handler does stopPropagation()(), then your handler is probably running too late to be effective, because the handlers are executed in order of registration. So you need to make sure to register your event listener as soon as possible in the page.

Comment: I have added a second solution in case the finicky event ordering is problematic for you.